# Observables in covariant formulation of electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

I feel some confusion regarding how and what can be measured in covariant formulation of electromagnetism. 
In [Why is the electromagnetic four-potential $A_{\mu}$ not an observable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189913/28273) it seems that the 4-potential can not be measured.
What are the observables- is the 4-current and/or the electromagnetic field tensor measurable and how?

Feels like the engineering side of things are harder to find information on...